# Wordpress query with variable in SQL

Tags: php, wordpress

Why this code gives empty array:

```
$category = 3;
$man = 'HP';

$query_join = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT wp_products.product_manufacturer
                                    FROM wp_products
                                    JOIN wp_categories
                                    ON wp_products.category_id=wp_categories.id
                                    WHERE ' . $category . ' = wp_products.category_id
                                    AND ' . $man . ' = wp_products.product_manufacturer
                                ');
var_dump($query_join);
```

And this code gives array with one result:

```
$category = 3;


$query_join = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT wp_products.product_manufacturer
                                    FROM wp_products
                                    JOIN wp_categories
                                    ON wp_products.category_id=wp_categories.id
                                    WHERE ' . $category . ' = wp_products.category_id
                                    AND "HP" = wp_products.product_manufacturer
                                ');
var_dump($query_join);
```

What do I have to do with variable in first code to get result like in secound?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
AND ' . $man . ' = wp_products.product_manufacturer
```

would produce

```
AND HP = wp_products.product_manufacturer
    ^^----
```

Note the lack of quotes around `HP`, which makes the DB interpret that as a **FIELD** name.

Try

```
 AND "' . $man . '" = wp_products.product_manufacturer
     ^------------^
```

note the extra quotes. And note that you are wide-open to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).